# why is my variable empty in my controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

I am trying to make an upload function to upload multiple files. But everytime if i check in my controller where I send the data to the variable is empty. What am I doing wrong please help.

This is the form where i get the myfiles variable

```html
 <form name="Document" method="post" action enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="file" id="documento" name="myFiles[]" required="required" multiple>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

This is my script that i wrote that makes it an array and get the files based on the id documentto.

```js
 $(document).on('click', '#btnSaveUploadedFiles', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                var fileArray = [];
                var fileBag = new FormData();
                var files = document.getElementById('documento').files;
                var arrayOfAllUploadedFiles = Array.from(files);
                fileArray.forEach(file => fileBag.append("myFiles[]", file));

                console.log(files);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ admin.generateUrl("uploadFiles") }}",
                    traditional: true,
                    data: {
                        "files": fileBag,
                        "uniqId": "{{ admin.uniqId }}",
                        "reservation": {{ admin.subject.id }}
                    },
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function () {
                        Swal.fire({
                            title: "test",
                            icon: "success",
                            confirmButtonText: "Sluiten"
                        });
                    },
                });
            });
```

This is my controller of symfony where i get the data from the {{ admin.generateurl.uploadfiles }}

```php
public function uploadFilesAction(Request $request)
    {

        $reservationID = $request->get('reservation');
        $files = $request->files;
        dd($files);
        $directory = "images/uploads/";

    foreach ($files as $uploadedFile) {
        // name the resulting file
        $name = $reservationID;
        $file = $uploadedFile->move($directory, $name);

        // do something with the actual file
        $this->doSomething($file);
    }

    // return data to the frontend
    return new JsonResponse();
    }
```

if you need more information ask me

Comment: Shouldnt it be `$files = $request->get('files');` after you wrapped the files in your ajax JSON object ?!

Comment: You have a `multipart/form-data` form, but actual submission is done with AJAX so I'd expect to see everything inside Symfony's equivalent for `$_POST`.

Comment: @lapskaus when i am doing `$files = $request->get('files');` the response is also empty

Comment: Please confirm that the data is present in ajax. Isnt the `fileArray` always empty and you iterate over an empty array to fill your dataset ? I guess is should be `arrayOfAllUploadedFiles .forEach(...`